# Why is my aggregate function not summing properly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

So I have this code below, and for some reason, the EstHrs being returned is wrong.  It's correct for most rows, but for others, the value returned, is doubled, tripled.  The values that are off seem to be off by a multiple amount (x2, x3, etc).  Not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
SELECT
   s.JobNo,
   ROUND(SUM(r.TotEstHrs), 3) AS EstHrs
FROM Scheduling s JOIN OrderRouting r ON s.JobNo = r.JobNo 
  AND s.WorkCntr = r.WorkCntr
WHERE s.WorkCntr = 'Cutting'
  AND r.OrderNo NOT IN ('44444', '77777')
GROUP BY s.JobNo;
```

Table structure:

**Scheduling:**

JobNo (text)

WorkCntr (text)

**OrderRouting:**

JobNo (text)

WorkCntr (text)

TotEstHrs (number)

Comment: Most likely due to your join returning multiple rows for one OrderRouting. I.e. if you have two OrderRouting rows or two Scheduling rows with the same JobNo and WorkCentre, then the SUM will be whatever multiple of the number of matches on those two columns. If possible, try joining on a primary key.

Comment: Maybe you could try simplifying your query, You can solve it without using the Scheduling table

Comment: I need the Scheduling table, that's where the open jobs live.  OrderRouting has all the jobs, including the finished ones

Comment: What data type is ToEstHrs? `INT`,`BIGINT`,`DECIMAL`,`FLOAT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause would be duplication of JobNo & WorkCntr in the Scheduling table.

EDIT...

```
WITH 
    cte_DistinctScheduling AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            s.JobNo
        FROM 
            dbo.Scheduling s
        WHERE 
            s.WorkCentr = 'Cutting'
        )
SELECT 
    ds.JobNo,
    ROUND(SUM(r.TotEstHrs), 3) AS EstHrs
FROM
    cte_DistinctScheduling ds
    JOIN dbo.OrderRouting r
        ON ds.JobNo = r.JobNo
WHERE 
    r.WorkCntr = 'Cutting'
    AND r.OrderNo NOT IN ('44444', '77777');
```

Comment: I ran the schedule table by itself and you're correct, there are duplicate entries for the same job number.  It's really dumb, I'll have to figure out a workaround.  Thanks

Comment: Glad to help... One simple solution to remove the dupes would be to use a CTE (or derived table) to distinct out Scheduling.JobNo. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, you forgot the group by, but added it and it works perfectly